# Finding the cumulative sum with different function call

Tags: php

I am trying to get the cumulative sum of the 'count' from the SQL query , which is called from function `getCumChartStatusesByWeek`  with different parameters.
But the variable `cumulativeSum` is showing error as `'Undefined variable'`, and only the actual count is displayed, not the cumulative sum.

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

```
$jsonDataCumArray = [];
$cumulativeSum = 0;

$jsonDataCumArray[] = getCumChartStatusesByWeek($statusID, $wwAreaMinus1, $wwAreaNow);
$jsonDataCumArray[] = getCumChartStatusesByWeek($statusID, $wwAreaNow, $wwAreaPlus1);
$jsonDataCumArray[] = getCumChartStatusesByWeek($statusID, $wwAreaPlus1, $wwAreaPlus2);
$jsonDataCumArray[] = getCumChartStatusesByWeek($statusID, $wwAreaPlus2, $wwAreaPlus3);

//Quick function used to grab data for the above bar graph

function getCumChartStatusesByWeek($statusID,$startTime1, $endTime1){
 global $db,$AndCustomersInString;
 $jsonCumData = [];
 $qCum =   "SELECT COUNT(*) as count 
         FROM request_meta rmm
         LEFT JOIN request_taxonomy rtt ON rtt.id = rmm.id
         WHERE rtt.req_a_id = $statusID
         AND rmm.req_id IN
             (SELECT r.req_id FROM requests r 
              WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(r.date_created,'%Y-%m-%e %H:%i:%s')) BETWEEN $startTime1 AND $endTime1                  
              $AndCustomersInString
             )
             AND rmm.meta_value='New' ";

         $row1 = $db->query($qCum)->fetchAll();
         $cumulativeSum +=  $row1['count'];
         $jsonCumData['NewRequests'] = $cumulativeSum;

      return $jsonCumData;
}
```

Result

```
    json
Array
(
    [y] => 2016-02-15
    [NewRequests] => 2
)
json
Array
(
    [y] => 2016-02-22
    [NewRequests] => 9
)
json
Array
(
    [y] => 2016-02-29
    [NewRequests] => 2
)
json
Array
(
    [y] => 2016-03-07
    [NewRequests] => 0
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because `$cumulativeSum` is **out of scope of the function**.

Either make `$cumulativeSum` `global` or pass it to the `function` as `argument`.

```
global $db,$AndCustomersInString, $cumulativeSum;
```

Or

```
$jsonDataCumArray[] = getCumChartStatusesByWeek($statusID, $wwAreaMinus1, $wwAreaNow, $cumulativeSum);
```

And

```
function getCumChartStatusesByWeek($statusID,$startTime1, $endTime1, $cumulativeSum){
   .....
}
```